# Choppy, slow "point to scroll" animation in safari on mac

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox, optimization, safari

I'm currently finishing up [this site](http://www.pickmixmagazine.com/wordpress):

When using firefox or safari on a mac, the "point-to-scroll" runs very slowly in comparison to Chrome.  On Windows 7, It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not Safari, any ideas would be greatly appreciated, the code I have used for the scroll function is below:

```
function handleMouse(e) {
  if (x && y) {
      var diffX=e.clientX-x;
      var diffY=e.clientY-y;
      window.scrollBy(diffX, diffY);}
      x = e.clientX;
      y = e.clientY;
}

document.onmousemove = handleMouse;
```